# Reading input inside assign activity in workflow4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am new to Workflow. I am creating a guessing game using sequence and flowchart. Inside the sequennce I have a Flowchart Activity.I invoked the flowchart activity inside the .completed event of sequence activity. But this code giving me unpredictable outputs,means after entering the input it is again showing me the new console line in prompt, if i enter any button it leading to exit. So next flowchart activity is not invoked at all. I found that where i used assign activity with console.readline() at that stage mainly giving me the unintended results. I am new to WF , I don't know main functionality and properties of Assign Activity. Some one please give me the clarity, thanks in Advance.

Sequence activity contains only Welcome writeline and assign activity for asking name and then other write line that's it.
In flowchart there are no. of flow decisions and writelines.Sometimes it is going to flowchart but in flowchart activity also where i have the assign activity with console line , fishy is happening there.
Here my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
       {

        var a = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1());

        a.Completed = e =>
        {
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new Flowchart(){guess=new System.Random().Next(1,100) });

        };
        a.Run();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you have a few questions here, if you can post you workflow file xaml content or a screen shot we can then advise better.

Comment: i need reputations to insert images, that's why i didn't........
I have a sequence with
1)Writeline - "Welc0me here"                                                                2)Assign Activity with Console.readline() for getting name of user
3)After that i have a flowchart

Comment: flowchart:
  1)Writeline to welcome again and the
  2)Assign activity to get the value of "guess" varible using console.readline()
 3)flowdecission to compare randomly generated number with guess variable a)if both matches then writeline to tell "Guess is correct"
       b)Else again goes to assign activity to get value of guess with console.readline()

Comment: @DotNetHitMan - Can u help me now??

Comment: I can, posting an answer ASAP